# gWidgets scale plots according to window size

Tags: r, gwidgets

I tried to create a GUI with two `ggraphics` elements inside holding two plots.
Everything works fine except the scaling of the plots when the `gwindow` is resized.

I wonder if the problem lies in the way I create the `ggroups` or, in the end, if it is possible at all.

I know that I can set absolute parameters for the plot's size, however, for usability reasons it would be nice if it scales with the size of the GUI's window (such as a normal plot does).

Here is a working example code:

```
require(gWidgets)
options('guiToolkit'='RGtk2')

window = gwindow("Test")

#The main group...
main_group = ggroup(horizontal = T, container = window)

#...including two groups (left and right)
left_side = ggroup(horizontal = F, container = main_group)
right_side = ggroup(horizontal = F, container = main_group)

#Something on the left
test_frame = gframe("Foo", container = left_side)
another_frame = gframe("bar", container=left_side)


#the two horizontally aligned plots on the right
plot1 = ggraphics(container=right_side)
dev1 = dev.cur();
plot2 = ggraphics(container = right_side)
dev2 = dev.cur();


Sys.sleep(0.5) # avoiding alignment errors
plot(rnorm(100,2))
dev.set(dev1)
plot(rnorm(100,2))
```

However, when only one plot is used it seems to scale at least vertically but not horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I've just found the `expand` parameter in the gWidgets doc...

So using

```
right_side = ggroup(horizontal = F, container = main_group, expand = T)
```

instead of

```
right_side = ggroup(horizontal = F, container = main_group)
```

did the trick.